# Error calculating percentage of download completed

Tags: ios, xcode

I have the following code for calculating the percentage and time remaining of a downloading file. I have following data from chilkat FTP2 module: byte/sec and total file size and file size remaining.

What is wrong? I still get high negative percent numbers and times that are negative or very small ( 0.00213 )

```
int Calcbytesreceived = [ftp.AsyncBytesReceived intValue];

int Calcdownloadrate = [ftp.DownloadRate intValue];

// data from FTP chilkat module: fileSize (bytes) ,  ForCalcbytesreceived (bytes) , ForCalcdownloadrate ( bytes / sec ) all Int format

double PercentOfFile = ( (double)Calcbytesreceived / (double)fileSize) * 100 ; 

double SecondsRemaining = ((double)fileSize - (double)Calcbytesreceived) / (double)Calcdownloadrate ;

double MinutesRemaining = (double)SecondsRemaining / 60 ;

NSLog(@"percent loaded = %@", PercentOfFile);
```

Answer (score 5):

PercentOfFile is of type double. You need to use "%f" instead of "%@" to display a double value. Change your last line to:

```
NSLog(@"percent loaded = %f", PercentOfFile);
```

EDIT: Here is a link to a good resource for determining when to use different NSLogs

http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSLog

Comment: Yes. And you could declare `Calcbytesreceived` and `Calcdownloadrate` as `double` from the beginning instead of casting them every time.

Comment: OK. Thank you and how do I handle the MinutesRemaining? `NSLog(@"percent loaded = %f", Minutesremaining);`does not work.The result is most of the time negative ... ???

Comment: Hmm... do you get accurate results if you log SecondsRemaining? If not, check the value of Calcdownloadrate - since it updates throughout the FTP transaction, it might not have a valid value at the time that you are getting it.